# Calculate difference between two queries's timestamp output in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two queries with me, each gives a timestamp as an output.

```
1. select createdon from table1 where condition1;
2. select createdon from table1 where condition2;
```

Both the outputs are like this,

```
2022-06-26 16:05:04
```

The query I wrote is like this:

```
select extract epoch from ((Select createdon from table1 where condition1) - (select createdon from table1 where condition2);
```

But I'm not getting any output. How can I calculate the difference between these timestamps in days and hours?

Comment: Just fix your syntax, add parenthesis. `select extract('epoch' from ....)`. You may extract 'day' or 'hour' instead of 'epoch' or divide the epoch seconds by 86400 or 3600 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

you ca use this sql for extract interval

```
select ((Select createdon from table1 where condition1) - (select createdon from table1 where condition2))::interval;
```